# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':myapplication:preHuaweiDebugBuild'

Tags: java

I wanted to change my existing project to a Library to do a encapsulation, but after that I created a new moudle and tried to reference the Library, but it kept reminding me that I could not determine the dependency of a certain task, which was very annoying now

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':myapplication:preHuaweiDebugBuild'.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':myapplication:huaweiDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   Could not find :UDSDKV4.0.LL190509.20190522:.
     Required by:
         project :myapplication > project :app
```